# Term encompassing thread, string, lanyard, and wire

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

Looking for a general term for things one would store on a spool -- thread, string, lanyard, wire, that sort of thing.  Things that occur in long lines and will get tangled up if you don't organize them properly.

Comment: "Fiber" or "thread" might work... (even though you mentioned "thread" already - I think "thread" is actually fairly generic)

Comment: Is there a motivation for the need for such a generic term? You've articulated the concept but that doesn't guarantee a concise existing term in English.

Comment: @Mitch: Yes, I asked because I have a motivation.  I understand that not all concepts map to English words.

Comment: @chaos: OK then, what is your motivation?

Comment: @Mitch: Naming a software object that can take on any of these as specific forms.  (I don't see how knowing this helps anything.)

Comment: Oh, then having some perfect single word in some long narrative is not important, but labeling for code? Then call it what it is: spool-stored lengths

Comment: @Mitch: I'd really like something more concise, and the ideal would be something that could be reasonably made user-visible in some circumstances.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might refer to all of those as *line*, which means

> a length of cord, rope, wire, or other material serving a particular purpose

Answer (score 2):

All things that could be stored on a spool have coils.  So perhaps the word 'windings' in combination with coils.  As in: "Windings, left uncoiled, are hazardous."

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I'm considering using "filament".